# How to integrate koa2-ratelimit inside Strapi Post request

Tags: strapi

I have a strapi project which is having a contact us form done in vue-Js frontend. However there is a problem that When I am trying to post contact us, its allowing unlimited time of post requests. I am trying to implement a `koa2-ratelimit` but not sure how to add it with strapi v4 and seems like the information provided are in very experienced level. can anyone help to solve this problem to limit this particular post request maximum limit to 1 per minute
API -: api/contact-uses

Comment: You can accomplish this via route middleware, I haven't created an example of this yet, but you can get some ideas from this blog post https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-build-a-secure-web-app-with-strapi-policies but I am also going to see if I can build an example this weekend. You may also find this useful too https://github.com/derrickmehaffy/strapi-middleware-ratelimit